# Does every smooth surjective function have a smooth right inverse?

Tags: real-analysis, category-theory

If you feel this question might be too broad, let me know and I’ll try to get more specific.

> If $r \colon I → J$ is a smooth surjective function between perfect subspaces $I$ and $J$ of $ℝ$, can we always find a right inverse smooth function $s \colon J → I$, i.e. $r∘s = \operatorname{id}_J$?
>   In the same fashion, does every smooth injective $s \colon I → J$ have an smooth injective left inverse?

**Edit**: As pointed out by GCD in the comment, a necessary condition is for the derivatives of $r$ and $s$ to be non-singular (in $s(J)$ and $J$ or in $r(I)$ and $I$ respectively at least).
So one should at least assume that.
This also implies that $r$ and $s$ are locally invertible there.

*For example*:
Loosening the question a bit,
if $s \colon J → I$ is continuous and injective, then by the intermediate value theorem we can conlude that $s$ is monotone on every connected component of $J$.
If $J = [a,b]$ is a compact interval, one can define a retraction $r \colon I → J$ by inverting $s$ on $s(J)$ whilst being constantly $a$ or $b$ on the parts above and below $s(J)$ in $I$.
But what is if we really talk about smooth functions?

Where can I find a discussion on this and are there some nice counter-examples?

---

Maybe it is fruitful to also generalize and rephrase this question in terms of categories.

I want to investigate the relations between the following kinds of maps in $\mathcal{C}$:

- surjective maps [$o$]
- injective maps [$i$]
- right-cancellable maps (epics) [$e$]
- left-cancellable maps (monics) [$m$]
- right-invertible maps (split epics/retractions) [$r$]
- left-invertible maps (split monics/sections) [$s$]

where $\mathcal{C}$ is some adequate category of topological/smooth spaces.

In the square brackets stands the name I’d prefer to use for maps with the corresponding property.
Categorically we have the implications “$r ⇒ e$” and “$s ⇒ m$”.
In concrete categories I understand we also have “$o ⇒ e$” and “$i ⇒ m$”.

Now, I’m mainly interested in the implications “$e ⇒ r$” and “$m ⇒ s$“, that is:

> For which categories $\mathcal{C}$ of euclidian (topological/smooth) spaces is:
>
> - every epic a retraction, and
> - every monic a section?

And I’d be more than happy to have an answer only for categories in which the objects are perfect subspaces of $ℝ$ and morphisms are $C^1$ or $C^∞$.

Any help or references are appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Almost surely I don't fully understand your question, but what is wrong with $x^3:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: @GCD Nothing! I’ve forgotten about it. Thanks. But I’m also interested in a discussion of the conditions under which some left/right inverses might exist, so this doesn’t fully answer the question.